# Identify MOSFET and find equivalent - top marking "P40 1340" or "S36 1410"

Tags: power, mosfet, identification

Please, help identify this MOSFET and equivalent.  One circuit has them marked as "**P40 1340**"  and the other has "**S36  1410**".

It's part of a circuit of 2 MOSFETs that act as power switches controlled by an MCU pin.  **It operates down to 2 Volts and handles up to 3A.**

I am hoping to find the same or with equivalent rating. I found a MOSFET numbered as "TC1410", but it does not seem to have the same package even offered. And I could not find any MOSFETs with a marking of "1340".

EDIT:  If cannot identify them, I think this could be a substitute:
IRF7317TRPBF‎, Infineon Technologies,  MOSFET N/P-CH 20V 8-SOIC
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7317pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355f5b8de1b3d

DMC2038LVTQ-7‎, Mosfet Array N and P-Channel Complementary 20V 3.7A
https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/DMC2038LVT.pdf

[image: photo of MOSFET marked P40 1340]

[image: photo of MOSFETs marked S36 1410]

[image: schematic diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Diodes Incorporated DMP2008UFG](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP2008UFG.pdf) has a matching package and "marking information" in datasheet says S36.
[DMP4025SFG](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMP4025SFG.pdf) from the same manufacturer has marking P40.

The other numbers are production year/week.

Comment: Wow.,.thank you!  I am good at finding things but this one eluded me!